# Ember nested component inside SVG tag throws error

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to build an Ember component consisting of svg tags. The goal is to have a d3 visualization driven by Handlebars template and with the dynamic changes handled by the component. I'm running into an issue though.

My view template is as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{the-parent data=data}}
</script>
```

Component templates are as follows:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/the-parent">
    <svg {{bind-attr width=width height=height}}>
        <g {{bind-attr transform=transform}}>
            {{#each data}}
                {{the-child text=text}}
            {{/each}}
        </g>
    </svg>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/the-child">
    <text>Hello</text>
</script>
```

The parent component is defined as such:

```
App.TheParentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    height: function() {
        ...
    }.property(...),

    width: function() {
        ...
    }.property(...),

    transform: function() {
        ...
    }.property(...)
});
```

And I get the following error:

```
Assertion Failed: The metamorph tags, metamorph-93-start and metamorph-93-end, have different parents.
The browser has fixed your template to output valid HTML (for example, check that you have properly closed all tags and have used...<omitted>...')
```

If in the parent component template you replace the svg tag with a div tag and the g tag with a ul tag, and in the child component template you replace the text tag with a li tag, it works fine.

Any idea what's going on?

EDIT:

The specific assertion that fails is the following:

```
function _addMetamorphCheck() {
      EachView.reopen({
        _checkMetamorph: on('didInsertElement', function() {
          Ember.assert("The metamorph tags, " +
                       this.morph.start + " and " + this.morph.end +
                       ", have different parents.\nThe browser has fixed your template to output valid HTML (for example, check that you have properly closed all tags and have used a TBODY tag when creating a table with '{{#each}}')",
            document.getElementById( this.morph.start ).parentNode ===
            document.getElementById( this.morph.end ).parentNode
          );
        })
      });
    }
```

When it fails, the value of `document.getElementById( this.morph.start ).parentNode` is "g" and the value of `document.getElementById( this.morph.end ).parentNode` is "div#ember521.ember-view", the latter being the div tag of the parent component itself, so the tag parent to the svg tag. I tripled checked all the tags and I'm pretty sure none is left unclosed.

Comment: Does it not tell you the specific HTML error that failed the assertion? It should be within the part you omitted. When you use `{{#each}}` in a non-production environment, Ember is going to run tests and assert that the markup is valid. This is to ensure that the metamorph tags stay properly nested within the right DOM nodes. It doesn't look like you have improperly nested any tags... but Ember thinks you did. Each browser has slight differences in tidying bad markup, so they try to get you to follow w3c to the letter in some cases. I am pretty green with `svg` so this is likely a `gotcha`.

Comment: I updated my question with info on the failing assertion. I wonder why Ember thinks I improperly nested any tags... It seems to be related with the svg tags, because when I replace g with ul and text with li, it works. Is it possible the tests Ember runs for some reason don't work well with svg tags?

Comment: Hmmm... Have you checked to see if any of the property bindings are invalid or maybe throwing bad code? Sometimes if you accidentally forget to add `.property()` to a computed property it will return the function string and all hell breaks loose... Try removing the bindings, then adding them one by one. Try raw html. Like just raw svg tag and g tags. Set a static height and whatnot... I'm sure you get it.

Comment: Yeah, tried all that. But I'm thinking of something. Typically SVG tags other than the actual `<svg>` cannot be wrapped within traditional tags like `<div>`. See [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/foluzeka/1/edit): if you get rid of the div tags around the `<circle>` tag, then it works. So I'm thinking the problem is that Ember wraps every tag around these `<div>` metamorph tags, and that's what's messing everything up. Does that then mean that there's no way of dynamically generating SVG tags in a Handlebars template with Ember?

Comment: I didn't look _too_ much into your problem, but I think you ought to know that Ember (specifically jQuery) doesn't handle SVG tags the same way that it handles HTML tags. It's a [known issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5021), but there's no known fix yet. There are some hacks for certain scenarios, but overall, SVG is just bad to work with.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for linking to that issue. That seems indeed to be the problem. I guess I'll wait until HTMLBars is shipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! The trick is to not use Handlebars in `<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/the-child"></script>`. Define the tag in the component definition itself under the `tagName` hook and bind any attributes through the `attributeBinding` hook. See [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kofuy/3/edit) for a working solution. The reason this is working is that the template engine then does not add these weird metamorph tags.